# How to use the importrows method of google fusion tables API using google client api (gapi)

Tags: javascript, http, google-fusion-tables

Does anyone know how to do a succesful request to the importrows method of the fusiontables API using the google-api-javascript-client. I have other requests working, for example to list the columns of a certain table. So I am pretty sure the authentication is fine.

```
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.column.list({
            'tableId': tableId
          });
          request.execute(function(resp) {
            alert(resp.totalItems);
          });
        });
      }
```

This is the code I use to importrows (which is not working). For clarity I try to import only one record here:

```
function makeApiCallImportRows() {
  gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.table.importRows({
      'tableId': tableId,
      'uploadType' : 'media',
      'resource': {
          'media': {
            'contentType': 'application/octet-stream',
            'data': 'aa,1,ds,01-01-2013'
          }
        }

    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
    //only in ff:
    alert(resp.toSource());
    });
  });
}
```

The alert then says this:

> ({error:{errors:[{domain:"fusiontables", reason:"badImportInputEmpty",
>   message:"Content is empty."}], code:400, message:"Content is
>   empty."}})

So obviously my import is empty. What should my syntax be? I read in the fusiontables documentation that the CSV data should be specified in the request body part, but I don't know how to do that using the gapi javascript library.

Comment: I found a solution, I can achieve what I want by doing this:  function makeApiCallImportRows() { 
       var request = gapi.client.request({
         'path': '/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/'+tableId+'/import',
         'method': 'POST',
         'params': {'uploadType': 'media'},
         'headers' : {'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'}, 'body': '9,9,9,2013\n8,8,8,2014'
       });
       request.execute(function(resp) {
     alert(resp.toSource());
          });
       
      }

Answer (score 3):

For those who are interested. Here is  way to do this:

```
function makeApiCallImportRows() { 
  var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/'+tableId+'/import',
    'method': 'POST',
    'params': {'uploadType': 'media'},
    'headers' : {'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'},
    'body': '9,9,9,2013\n8,8,8,2014\n'
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    alert(resp.toSource());
    });
}
```